# Use of law of total expectation without checking integrability

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation, expected-value

$\newcommand{\E}{\mathbb E}$In basic probability classes, people often use the formula, namely the law of total expectation
$$\E[X]=\E[\E[X\mid Y]]$$
without checking integrability of $X$.

I can't get my head around it, because we sometimes use it to check the integrability of $X$... Wow! We don't even know if $\E[X\mid Y]$ exists, yet we use it.

**Example.**
For a simple example, I wanted to do it properly. For instance, consider  nonnegative integrable random variables $Z$ and $X_i$ i.i.d. independent of $Z$.  We need to check whether $$\sum_{i= 1}^ZX_i $$
is integrable. I can do it like this
$$\E\left[\sum_{i= 1}^ZX_i \right]=\E\left[\E\left[\sum_{i= 1}^ZX_i\mid Z\right] \right]=\E\left[\sum_{i=1}^Z \E[X_i] \right]=\E[Z]\E[X_1]$$
But I thought this is cheating, so I considered $X\mathbb I_{X<K}$ for some constant $K>0$, then we have
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^Z X_i\mathbb I_{X_i<K} \leq ZK
\end{align}
This is clearly integrable. So we can apply the same steps as before "legally" to show integrability and then MCT does the rest of the work
\begin{align}
\E\left[\sum_{i=1}^Z X_i\right]\stackrel{\text{MCT}}{=}\lim_{K\to\infty}\E\left[\sum_{i=1}^Z X_i\mathbb I_{X_i<K} \right]=\lim_{K\to\infty}\E[X_1\mathbb I_{X_1<K}]\E[Z]\stackrel{\text{MCT}}{=}\E[X_1]\E[Z]
\end{align}
Do something similar always works, giving us the reason why people just use it? Indeed, I guess it is boring to repeat these kind of steps if it always works, therefore my question:

> **Question.** Can we actually apply the law of total expectation to show integrability? If the answer is "yes", is there a general proof? If the answer is "no", are there examples where it fails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the usual laws of conditional expectation work for nonnegative random variables, integrable or not, if you allow the value $+\infty$. For instance, if $X$ is nonnegative, $E[X \mid Y]$ will always exist, but potentially could equal $+\infty$ with positive probability.  And if $X$ is nonnegative and not integrable, then you will get $E[E[X \mid Y]] = +\infty$ as well (i.e. $E[X \mid Y]$ is nonnegative and not integrable).  These cases are often left as exercises since it is a little tedious to write out the proofs, but you can show it by considering "cut off" random variables like $X_n = X 1_{X \le n}$ and using monotone convergence.

The properties do not necessarily hold for signed random variables that may not be integrable.    However, you can determine whether a random variable $X$ is integrable by computing $E[|X| \mid Y]$ and seeing if $E[E[|X| \mid Y]] < \infty$, and if so then you will know that $E[X] = E[E[X \mid Y]]$.

Comment: So it actually makes sense to use the law of total expectation for checking integrability. Many thanks! I suddenly remember that there is an exercise like that in Rick Durret's book. Silly me that I forgot about it. Thanks again!